# Connect one signal to many slots

Tags: c++, qt

in my C++ based BlackBerry 10 app I have a custom class that uses QNetworkAccessManager to handle network connections. The requestFinished(..) method of QNetworkAccessManager object emits a signal when it receives some data.

The thing is, many outside classes are interested in this signal. So, I have many slots connected to this signal. My problem is that, in those slots, I may be doing some UI related stuff -- so I may not want that once the signal is emitted, ALL slots get called simultaneously all the time.

Rather I may want that, at one point in time, the signal calls only one slot, at another point in time, another slot, and etc. What are the ways to do this???

I thought I could do is using different QNetworkAccessManager objects (below) -- but I have heard it is not recommended??? e.g., what are other ways??? Thank you.

```
 MyNetworkClass *network1 = new MyNetworkClass();
 bool res = QObject::connect(network1, SIGNAL(signalSuccess(QVariant)), this, SLOT(CustomSLot1(QVariant)));

    MyNetworkClass *network2 = new MyNetworkClass();
 bool res = QObject::connect(network2, SIGNAL(signalSuccess(QVariant)), this, SLOT(CustomSLot2(QVariant)));

    MyNetworkClass *network3 = new MyNetworkClass();
 bool res = QObject::connect(network3, SIGNAL(signalSuccess(QVariant)), this, SLOT(CustomSLot3(QVariant)));
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Qt application runs only 1 thread. This means nothing can be asyncronous. When one signal is fired, the slot function is run before anything else happens.

If you want to keep UI responsive and handle 3 functions at the same time, you need to thread them. At the beginning of the slot-function, start a thread where you execute the actual functionality.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/thread-basics.html

Qt also has asynchronous functions:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtconcurrentrun.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically what Gjordis is saying you have to run the custom class where the `QNetworkAccessManager` resides asynchronously. You have 2 simple choices :

- Either invoke asynchronous the methods of your class using [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtconcurrentrun.html)
- Either handle this class events in another thread, see [this excellent minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread). The only thing is that the `doWork()` mentionned is really a `doInit()` or `startWork()` depending on the situation.

With both of these cases it is ***primordial to interact with the class only using signals and slots*** , otherwise you may encounter races conditions. Which means the "consumer" UI thread should not use getters\setters. Locking is not a good option, as the UI thread will require to perform an eventually blocking operation to get his data.

Comment: Exactly. What I said. But fancier and more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You should emit different signals in sequence from the same Object: a signal for every different object that is interested.
In this way you can decide the order and decide if send message to all or only to some.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense... One signal is received by all listeners. It doesn't tackle the problem too...

Comment: @UmNyobe: of course, the listeners have to be connected to different signals... Instead of different senders (like suggested user2054339), I simply suggest to use different signals.

Comment: to add to this... it doesn't have to be N-to-N. You could have different levels of signals: non-gui, some-gui, some-more-gui, etc. The OP never really indicated if they wanted to cancel remaining slots while inside an initial slot, or if the set of slots to be handled should be dynamic. Also, connections are dynamic. You can disconnect(), too, and then re-connect() later.