# C++ thread affinity in QT error

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a simple Qt application that sends files from a folder to a server.

When there is no internet connection, the expected behavior would be to save the file for later in an "offline" folder. Then, once a couple of minutes the application itself (in a different thread) would have to check that folder to see if some files await being sent.

Here's some code, I stripped some unnecessary lines:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWin win;
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwin.cpp:

```
MainWin::MainWin(QWidget * parent) : QWebView(parent)
{

    m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    m_communicationHandler = new TestNetwork(this, m_network);

    // harvie
    Harvester * harvie = new Harvester(m_network);
    harvie->start();


}
```

harvester.cpp:

Header:

```
class Harvester : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QNetworkAccessManager * m_network;
    Harvester(QNetworkAccessManager * m_network);
...
}
```

Source:

```
Harvester::Harvester(QNetworkAccessManager * m)
{
    qDebug() << "harvie start" << endl;
    this->m_network = m;
}
```

...

```
bool Harvester::sendFile(QFileInfo *fileInfo) {

    connect(this->m_network,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(validateReply(QNetworkReply*)));

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    QHttpPart filePart;
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("text/xml")); // @todo test
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"someFile\"; filename=\"" + fileInfo->baseName() + ".xml\""));

    QFile *file = new QFile(fileInfo->filePath());
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart


    multiPart->append(filePart);

    qDebug() << "post" << endl;

    QNetworkReply *reply = this->m_network->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("XXX")), multiPart);

    multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply

    return true;
}
```

Here's the error I receive:

```
Warning: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x3e46c30), parent's thread is QThread(0x3dd6d50), current thread is Harvester(0x3e47eb8)
```

I guess the QNetworkAccessManager is conflicting when trying to send a request from another thread, even if I use the same pointer.

One other solution that I did not tried yet would be to run harvester as a separate process, but first I'd like to solve it by threading.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[qt thread with movetothread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread)

http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qthread.html#details

http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qobject.html#moveToThread

Try this:

```
Harvester::Harvester(QNetworkAccessManager * m)
{
    qDebug() << "harvie start" << endl;
    this->m_network = m;

    m_network->moveToThread(this); // Change thread affinity!
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the first link I posted in my answer shows a way to setup a worker thread.  You could move all your initializations for your `QNetworkAccessManager` into the worker/task.  Just make sure that you are moving it to the right thread.

Comment: I've handled QThreads 4 or 5 different ways.  This blog: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ spurred some changes in the `QThread` docs to fit a "worker"/"producer" model better.  You can subclass QThread, but you need to be careful about how you clean up everything, how you connect everything, and to initialize qobjects the thread uses in the top of the `run()` function.

Comment: ok thank you for your help, I'll try that tomorrow and will let you know if I made it through.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I've had a good bit of head ache over thread affinity garbage in the past.  The Qt Developer Days cover a bunch of awesome topics including MultiThreading:  http://qt-project.org/videos#c-89