# How to ensure button closes the application regardless of the widget structure?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-designer

If you have a simple `QMainWindow` or even app with single `QWidget`, you can connect any button to `close()` slot on it and it will close the program. You can even do this in designer without any coding:

[image: image description]

But this will cease to work once you have more complex structure where `MainMenu` is a child of another widget. Under that circumstances, the `close` slot only hides `MainMenu` (so you just see black screen) but the application keeps running. I was wondering if there's non-hacky way to terminate the program regardless of the widget hierarchy.

Calling `abort` or similar methods are considered hacky. There's allways some cleanup that must occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply connect your `QPushButton::clicked()` signal to the [QCoreApplication::quit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) slot. This will close the application for good when button is clicked.

Note: `QCoreApplication` can be accessed via `qApp` global object.

```
connect( myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()) );
```

You mentioned in the OP:

> you can connect any button to close() slot on it and it will close the program

Note that this is not necessarily true. It's only true if [QGuiApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#instance) is `true` (which is the default, I must admit).

Answer (score 0):

Roughly:

- Use Qt parent\children model
- call the static method`QCoreApplication::exit` when you need to stop the application. It calls `QEventLoop::exit` on the main (GUI) thread. It triggers the destruction of top level objects as well as their children
- Optionally, If you start work threads, do it using the [movetoThread design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread) . Then the owner of the QThread object just need to do the following:

  ```
  QThread workthread;
  workthread.exit(code);
  workthread.wait(time_ms);
  if(workthread.isRunning())
  {
     workthread.terminate();
  }
  ```

In general you don't want to use terminate.

Comment: I don't understand the thread part. I'm not starting any threads manually - maybe I don't need that part? The `QEventLoop::exit` is static? If not, how do I access it from my ui class? I will probably need to call it from the click event handler.

Comment: you dont need that part if you are not starting threads. edited