# Qt: QObject. Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, asynchronous, signals-slots

I have a problem, I'm trying to synchronize some `QThread`s with the main GUI and I have not good results!

I have a main window (I have some windows but the problem seems to be the same) that will interact with two kind of devices: A serial port (using qserialport) and a camera (using opencv).

In order to make them work, I need to use parallel processing. I made three QThreads:
* One to make synchronizations between devices and main window (principally, for complex operations)
* One to manage the serial port (using libqt5serialport)
* One for manage vision algorithms.

In order to communicate between these process, first, I'm trying to use signals and slots (also, probably I will use shared memory, mutex or a combination of them).

When I try to connect signals from my Serial Port object to slots in my `QThread`, the slot is not called and I receive a warning (in execution time):
`QObject`: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

The code is very simple, the code of Vision is not implemented at this code, I need to be sure that I can communicate the procecess probably is very conceptual, when I try to stand, i cannot.

action.cpp:

```
#include "action.h"

Action::Action(QObject *parent, estadoGeneral *Estado)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    myEstado = Estado;

//Create new QThreads, one for camera aon other for serial port
    tCommunication = new ActionCommunication(this, myEstado);
    tVision = new ActionVision(this, myEstado);

}

Action::~Action()
{
    //TODO: free memory, stop, etc.
}

void Action::run()
{

    cout << "run() Action, id: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;

    Action me;
    QTimer myTimer;

    //Esto si funciona
//    connect(myEstado->myCommunication, &SerialCommunication::readyRead, &myAction, &Action::readData);

#ifdef _ALIVE
//Signal works
    connect(&myTimer, &QTimer::timeout, &me, &Action::estaVivo);
    myTimer.start(10000);
#endif

    tCommunication->start();
//tVision->start();
    exec();
}

//Signal to connect
void Action::conectarSerie()
{
    cout << "Petición de conectar enviada por id " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;
    emyt sConectar();
}

void Action::enviarComando(int Comando)
{
    cout << "Petición de comando " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;
    emyt sEnviarComando1(Comando);
}
void Action::enviarComando(int Comando, int arg1)
{
    cout << "Petición de comando " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;
    emyt sEnviarComando2(Comando, arg1);
}

//Just a test
void Action::estaVivo()
{
    cout << "Action está vivo, signal id: " << this->currentThreadId() << endl;
}

//QThread to manage serial port
ActionCommunication::ActionCommunication(QObject *parent, estadoGeneral *Estado)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    mainParent = parent;
    myEstado = Estado;
}

ActionCommunication::~ActionCommunication()
{
//TODO
}

void ActionCommunication::run()
{
    cout << "run() ActionCommunication, id: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;

    myEstado->myCommunication = new SerialCommunication();
    ActionCommunication me;

    me.myEstado = myEstado;
    //Connect the signals
    {
        connect(mainParent, SIGNAL(sConectar()), &me, SLOT(conectar()));
        connect(mainParent, SIGNAL(sEnviarComando1(int)), &me, SLOT(EnviarComando1(int)));
        connect(mainParent, SIGNAL(sEnviarComando2(int, int)), &me, SLOT(EnviarComando2(int, int)));

//Here is the problem
//*******************
        connect(myEstado->myCommunication, SIGNAL(readyStatus(int,int,int,int,int)),\
                &me, SLOT(readyStatus(int,int,int,int,int)));
    }
    exec();
}

//Try to communicate, it works
void ActionCommunication::conectar()
{
    cout << "connect - ActionCommunication id " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    myEstado->myCommunication->configurePort(myEstado->mysSettings);

    if(myEstado->myCommunication->openSerialPort()) emyt sConectado(true);
    else emyt sConectado(false);
}

//Send commands to serial port, it works
void ActionCommunication::EnviarComando1(int comando)
{

    cout << "Comando en ActionCommunication id " << QThread::currentThreadId();
//nComando is an enum, I cast in order to send via signal
    myEstado->myCommunication->enviarComando((nComando) comando);
}

void ActionCommunication::EnviarComando2(int comando, int arg1)
{

    cout << "Comando en ActionCommunication id " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    myEstado->myCommunication->enviarComando((nComando) comando,(nComando) arg1);
}
//Here is the problem, i never receive the signal sent by serialport, that is a `qserialport`
// ****************************************************************************************
// When the signal is received, I got the warning
void ActionCommunication::readyStatus(int id, int x, int y, int z, int t)
{
    cout << "Id: " << id << "x" << x << "..." << endl;
}

/******************
//Not implemented, interface to operate with opencv classes.
******************/
ActionVision::ActionVision(QObject *parent, estadoGeneral *Estado)
    : QThread(parent)
{

}

ActionVision::~ActionVision()
{

}

void ActionVision::run()
{

}
```

action.h:

```
#ifndef ACCION_H
#define ACCION_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

#include "helpers.h"
#include "estadogeneral.h"
#include "vision.h"
//Here is the code that emit the signal, inherits QSerialPort
#include "comunicacionserie.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QImage;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ActionCommunication : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ActionCommunication(QObject *parent = 0, estadoGeneral *Estado=NULL);
    estadoGeneral *myEstado;
    ~ActionCommunication();

    QObject *mainParent;

    CommunicationSerie *myCommunication;

public slots:
    void conectar();
    void EnviarComando1(int comando);
    void EnviarComando2(int comando, int arg1);
// ********************* Problematic slot *******************
    void readyStatus(int id, int x, int y, int z, int t);

signals:
    void sConectado(bool);

protected:
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:

};

class ActionVision : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ActionVision(QObject *parent = 0, estadoGeneral *Estado=NULL);
    ~ActionVision();

protected:
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:

    estadoGeneral *myEstado;

};


class Action : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Action(QObject *parent = 0, estadoGeneral *Estado=NULL);
    ~Action();

    int irAFiducial(int nFiducial, bool esGlobal);
    void estaVivo();

    ActionCommunication *tCommunication;
    ActionVision *tVision;

    void conectarSerie();
    void enviarComando(int Comando);
    void enviarComando(int Comando, int arg1);
signals:
    void sConectar();
    void sEnviarComando1(int);
    void sEnviarComando2(int, int);
protected:
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:

    estadoGeneral *myEstado;
};


#endif // ACCION_H
```

PS: 
Another test: I can connect to `readyRead` with this `QThread` (signal emitted in my method, this signal worked for me without QThreads), but not to my own signal in CommunicationSerial, that has an object called serial and type `QSerialPort.
connect(miEstado->miCommunication->serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()),\
                &me, SLOT(datosPorLeer()));` // See note 5

Returned Id's (`QThread::CurrentThreadId()`)

---

main process id: 0x7f9ae9b2eac0 (main window, QObject)

Method run() of Action Id: 0x7f9ac382b700 (QThread)

Method run() of ActionCommunication Id: 0x7f9ac302a700 (Another QThread)

Id inside my QSerialPort  based object (CommunicationSerial): 0x7f9ac302a700, printed on CommunicationSerial constructor

Id of slot ActionCommunication::Conectar(): 0x7f9ac302a700 (will be the same where my program fails)

Note1: I have translated some part of my code in order to make more easy to understand. Sorry if I have made a mistake, I think that the problem is very clear and I cannot understand what is happening. QSerialPort is running with the same id as ActionCommunication, and I cannot understand the warning.

Note2: The problem appears when I will receive information from Serial Port (`CommunicationSerial`), I connect without problems, and when the device send some information, the slot `readyData` is not executed. If I use this code without `QThread` (directly from the main window code) I have not problems.

Note3: When I will receive data, the warning appears (QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread), also I receive this second message:
(Parent is QSerialPort(0x7f6ac4002c80), parent's thread is AccionComunicacion(0x1dbe810), current thread is QThread(0x1d4be30)
Note that they are pointers and probably them has changed from the last time.

Also, if I try to use `CommunicationSerial->moveToThread(&me)` or `CommunicationSerial->moveToThread(this)` in `run()` method of `ActionCommunication`, the warning is the same.

Note 4: Also, I have tried CommunicationSerial to inherit QObject (It inherited QSerialPort) and adding an QSerialPort object inside CommunicationSerial and I have added the methods that I need to do this. The results are the same.

Note 5: I have added a connection to `readyRead()` in CommunicationSerial->serial, that is, to `QSerialPort` object, and it works normally, but I continue with the same problem to connect `readyStatus` in `CommunicationSerial` (my own signal) receiving the mentioned error.

** I continue sending data, but I cannot receive `readyStatus` signal.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0x7f6ac4002c80), parent's thread is AccionComunicacion(0x1dbe810), current thread is QThread(0x1d4be30)
Note that they are pointers and probably them has changed from the last time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread

Comment: Hello Alexander! Thanks for your repply! I continue with the problem, I cannot understand the error, I tried to move the QSerialPort objecto to inside CommunicationSerial and make CommunicationSerial QObject (instead of QSerialPort) and moving CommunicationSerial to the QThread but i get the same results. Also, I do the same moovingo to &me, the only change is the moment when I receive the error from QT, but the error is the same. I go to edit my post adding a note (Note3).