# Qt: slots are not being called from the second thread

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to update UI from the second thread, I have created slots which are going to be called from other thread by signaling, but somehow it is not being called from the other thread. Below is the code:

**WorkerThread.h**

```
class WorkerThread: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WorkerThread();
    ~WorkerThread();

public slots:
    void onStart();
signals:
    void sendMessage(const QString& msg, const int& code);
};
```

**WorkerThread.cpp**

```
#include "workerwhread.h"

WorkerThread::WorkerThread(){}

void WorkerThread::onStart(){
    emit sendMessage("start", 100);
}
```

**Usage:**

**MyWidget.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MyWidget;
}

class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();
private slots:
    void onGetMessage(const QString &msg, const int& code);
private:
    Ui::MyWidget *ui;
    QThread *thread = nullptr;
    WorkerThread *wt = nullptr;
};
```

**MyWidget.cpp**

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    wt = new WorkerThread;
    thread = new QThread;

    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, wt, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(ui->btStart, &QPushButton::clicked, wt, &WorkerThread::onStart);
    connect(wt, &WorkerThread::sendMessage, this, &MyWidget::onGetMessage);
    wt->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}
void MyWidget::onGetMessage(const QString &msg, const int& code)
{
    qDebug() << "message" << msg; // this never being called ????
}
```

**Note:** When I pass the connection type `Qt::DirectConnectoin`, then it is working, but the problem is it is not the GUI thread.

```
connect(wt, &WorkerThread::sendMessage, this, &MyWidget::onGetMessage, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

**Main**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/system.png"));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Did you run qmake? If  `Qt::DirectConnection` works it most likely indicates Q_OBJECT is missing or no QEventLoop is running. As you told Qt::DirectConnection is working - thus, your slot/signal connections are fine. You placed Q_OBJECT and have an eventloop. So there is no obvious error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: with the same code, `message "start"` is printed when pressing the button, so the `onGetMessage` slot is called. There doesn't seem to be an error in the posted code.

Comment: I know the code is really nice and clean, and I am master in writing clean and optimized code, but whatever I have done, it still not working. I am now going to be confusing with Qt single-slot mechanism. Wasted me a lot of time.

Comment: Should there be some connection between QThread signal started and a corresponding slot in WorkerThread? Maybe the thread just finishes right away with no work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039216/5781248

Comment: I tested your code on my machine and it's working, I'm using Qt 5.9.4 and I'm running on Fedora 27,  also instead of `MyWidget`, I'm using `MainWindow`, what is your working environment?

Comment: My environment is Qt 5.10.0, and the Qt designer is 4.5.0. Win 10. If it is working on your machine, then it means there is something wrong with 10.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and checking the code line by line, I finally found the problem. The reason was with overriding the `event()` function of `QWidget`, the return value of `event()` function is `bool`, so if you return a `true` it is OK and working well without throwing any runtime or compile-time error. But it will prevent `signal-slot` events to happen.

**So NOT** `return true`, but `return QWidget::event(event);` then it will slove the problem.